# Android: TextView automatically truncate and replace last 3 char of String

Tags: java, android, textview

If a `String` is longer than the `TextView`'s width it automatically wraps onto the next line. I can avoid this by using `android:singleLine` (deprecated) or by setting `android:inputType="text"`. What I need now is something that replaces the last 3 characters of my `String` with "**...**". Since I'm not using a monospace font this will always be different depending on the letters used in my `String`. So I'm wondering what's the best way to get the last 3 characters of a String in a `TextView` and replace them. Maybe there's already something implemented in the Android framework, since this must be a common problem.

Answer (score 328, accepted):

You should be able to use the "ellipsize" property of a text view:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text_mytext"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
/>
```

You may also need to apply gravity values to the layout too; I have sometimes seen "auto-stretching" views without them.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I have tried that before, but didn't work, because I used android:inputType="text" instead of android:singleLine="true" (which is supposed to be deprecated). But now I'm gonna stick with android:singleLine="true". Muchas gracias.

Comment: It still doesn't add the "...". For me, this question is not fully answered! This answer will make "short verylongword" to just "short" and not "short verylon..." On top of that you guys suggest using a deprecated attribute.

Comment: Works great, however singleLine is deprecated so you must use maxLines="1" instead. Side note, ellipsize works with multiple lines as well!

Comment: singleLine is deprecated. Use maxLines="1". just a comment to old answer

Comment: MaxLine=1 will truncate the textview in the middle. SingleLine=True works as expected.

Comment: @torre-lasley Using maxLines="1" and ellipsize doesn't work properly with API lower than 22 (tested on API 21 and API 16). For example this text `i have a abcdefghijklmhopqrstuvw` it should show as `i have a abcdefgh...` but instead it's showing as `i have a ...`

Comment: Using ConstraintLayout, I needed to use constrainedWidth="true" as well

Comment: maxLines="1" doesn't give the same result as singleLine="true"

Answer (score 35):

Found an interesting work-a-round for this problem.

```
maxLines=1
ellipsize=end
scrollHorizontally=true
```

The trick is that last statement about horizontal scrolling .... check it out.  It at least works on v2.2.

Answer (score 5):

Programmatically, you can use:

```
TextView tx = new TextView(this);
tx.setTextSize(13);
tx.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
tx.setTop(90);
tx.setText("Long text here");
tx.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
tx.setSingleLine(true);
tx.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add
 `android:ellipsize="end"` on XML 
and your code should look like this

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/newsTitleTextView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/newsThumbnailImageView"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:text="Analysts See Slower Bitcoin Hashrate Growth in 2022 Amid Market Correction "
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```