# Is there a way to check if a TextView's text is truncated

Tags: android, textview

Is there a way to check whether a TextView's text is truncated in my code?

Answer (score 13):

You can use method: getEllipsisCount

```
 public static boolean isTextTruncated( String text, TextView textView )
    {
        if ( textView != null && text != null )
        {

            Layout layout = textView.getLayout();
            if ( layout != null )
            {
                int lines = layout.getLineCount();
                if ( lines > 0 )
                {
                    int ellipsisCount = layout.getEllipsisCount( lines - 1 );
                    if ( ellipsisCount > 0 )
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
```

I found the answer at the following related post:

[Check if textview is ellipsized in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567235/check-if-textview-is-ellipsized-in-android)

Comment: What is the use of param `String text` ?

Comment: getLayout return null with me

Answer (score 0):

Don't think so but you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666736/android-textview-automatically-truncate-and-replace-last-3-char-of-string) to properly handle it if you only want the text to use one line.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3410024/1384628) topic

> ... You can create a Paint object with TextView2's text size and use breakText() to measure how many characters will fit in your TextView2's width...

It works for me