# How do I determine how much text will fit in a TextView in Android?

Tags: android, layout, textview

I have a layout that looks something like this:

```
[TextView 1] [TextView 2]
[ TextView 2 spill-over ]
```

Essentially, I need the contents of TextView 2 to wrap to the next line, but start where TextView 1 starts. I was thinking that if I knew how much text would fit into TextView 2 before it runs out of space on line one, I could take the rest of the text and put it in another TextView below the first two. So I need to measure how much text will fit into a TextView (which can be tricky because as far as I can tell, Android will try to break the text in a TextView at a good location so that it won't break a word in the middle if it can be avoided) or I need a new idea on how to lay this out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

groomsy

Comment: If this is possible, I have a feeling it will be a lot more complicated that it will be worth. Why can't you just append your TextView2's text to textview 1?

Comment: Different formatting. Plus, TextView 1 can sometimes be an ImageView. I've thought about putting everything in a WebView, but I don't know how I would stop at 2 lines though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259016/scale-text-in-a-view-to-fit/7259136#7259136

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately, Paint.breakText didn't return the exact same result as in was seen in my two-line TextView.

However, this worked

```
int numChars = textView.getLayout().getLineEnd(1);
```

(use numberOfLines - 1 as the parameter to it)

Ref
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout.html#getLineEnd(int)
[Set individual lines of TextView to different width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057820/set-individual-lines-of-textview-to-different-width)

Comment: This got me going down the right path with a related problem. A combination of `getLineCount` and `getLineStart` did the trick for me when custom trimming/"ellipsizing" a TextView.

Comment: Also, for anyone having an issue with `getLayout()` returning null, check this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19157650/how-to-get-height-of-view-inside-adapter-for-creating-sized-bitmap

Comment: @Ioeschg `getlayout()` returns `null`, but the above given link is not helpful. Can you tell what's going wrong?

Comment: how is this accepted answer, getting null in getLayout().

Answer (score 6):

You can create a Paint object with TextView2's text size and use `breakText()` to measure how many characters will fit in your TextView2's width.

(This is untested code - might need some slight modifications)

```
String textToBeSplit = arbitraryText; // Text you want to split between TextViews
float textView2Width = somehowGetItsWidth; // TextView2's width
float myTextSize = textView2.getTextSize();

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setTextSize(myTextSize); // Your text size
int numChars = paint.breakText(textToBeSplit, true, float textView2Width, null);
```

`numChars` tells you how many characters in `textToBeSplit` will fit in TextView2's width, enabling you to split it between your views.

Comment: Thank you for the rough example. I will work on this and let you know how it turns out.

Comment: Tried this and it almost worked. The problem was that the TextView uses a slightly different approach, especially when it has more than one line. The count would be 2-3 characters of. Found a better solution that I'll post as an answer

Comment: @dparnas hey did find answer for "The count would be 2-3 characters of"

Comment: make sure textview is drawn with text, this can be achieved with  using `.post{}`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need two TextViews in order to do this, you should always use as few views as possible and you can use a spannable in order to have two styles for the same textview.
For example with :

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
SpannableString text = new SpannableString(myString);

text.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(getContext(), R.style.myStyle), 0, 5, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
text.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(getContext(), R.style.myNextStyle), 6, 10, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

tv.setText(text, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```