# Set individual lines of TextView to different width

Tags: android, layout, textview

I'm trying to setup a TextView that contains two lines of text, the second line being shorter than the first one.

Is there a way to set up TextView's Layout instance (acquired via TextView.getLayout()) to truncate the second line, or is there another way that I'm not aware of?

**EDIT 1**

There were misinterpretations of my intentions: I'm trying to set a textview layouted in a way, that i can set arbitrary text and depending on the length the following happens:
If the text is long enough to start a second line, make the first line as wide as the textview's content width is, but the second line should be shorter, for example half as wide. But there should be a second line, if text is long enough.

I checked out abstract class Layout and it's subclasses, there is a function

```
public int getLineEnd(int line)
```

that returns the position of the last character for a line. A way could be to set the text, then check out how wide the second line is layouted and then change the text to a shorter version. Anyways, that seems to be a hacky way, which could be made much cleaner and more stable, if I could set a Layout instance myself (via a setter method, such as getter

```
TextView.getLayout().
```

Has anyone set a custom Layout to a subclass of Textview?

**EDIT 2 / My Own Solution**

Found a solution:
Now I'm checking if the second line overlaps with the region that was the reason for making the second line shorter. If so, I'm truncating the text.
Functions I used:

```
TextView.getLineCount()
TextView.getLayout().getLineStart(int line)
TextView.getLayout().getLineEnd(int line)
TextView.getPaint().measureText()
```

Maybe that helps a future anyone.

The question how to set an own layout still remains unanswered, though.

Comment: have you tried [setEllipsize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setEllipsize%28android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt%29)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `android:maxLines="1"` in your XML or `textView.setMaxLines(1);` in your Activity.

Comment: Also refer the following link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461824/how-to-programmatically-set-maxlenght-in-android-textview?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:maxLines

> Makes the TextView be at most this many lines tall.
>
> Must be an integer value, such as "100".
>
> This corresponds to the global attribute resource symbol maxLines.

and you can also use:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize

> If set, causes words that are longer than the view is wide to be
>   ellipsized instead of broken in the middle. You will often also want
>   to set scrollHorizontally or singleLine as well so that the text as a
>   whole is also constrained to a single line instead of still allowed to
>   be broken onto multiple lines.
>
> Must be one of the following constant values.
>
> none       start       middle      end         marquee         This corresponds to the
>   global attribute resource symbol ellipsize.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "\n" to mark the different lines in a String. And use the TextView.setGravity() method to define the TextView's Layout. For example,

```
mTextView.setText("Hello World Hello World\nSecond.");
mTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

And the preview of this TextView will be:

```
Hello World Hello World
        Second
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem,here is my solution:

---

here is the code,the truncateText method to calculate the text length and truncate.

```
public class LastLineControlTextView extends TextView{

private int mMaxLines;
private float mLastLineRatio = 0.5f;
private float mLastLineWidth;
private float mAllowLength;

public LastLineControlTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    mLastLineWidth = getWidth()*mLastLineRatio;
    mAllowLength = (mMaxLines-1)*getWidth()+mLastLineWidth;
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(getText())){
        truncateText(getText());
    }
}

@Override
public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
    super.setText(text, type);
    if(mAllowLength==0)
        return;
    truncateText(text);
}

@Override
public void setMaxLines(int maxlines) {
    super.setMaxLines(maxlines);
    mMaxLines = maxlines;
}

private void truncateText(CharSequence text){
    float width = Layout.getDesiredWidth(text, getPaint());
    int end = text.length();
    while(width > mAllowLength){
        width = Layout.getDesiredWidth(text, 0, end, getPaint());
        end--;
    }
    if(end==text.length())
        return;
    CharSequence processed = text.subSequence(0, end);
    System.out.println("end:"+end+"processed:"+processed);
    setText(processed);
}
}
```

---