# Get number of visible characters in textview when ellipsize was applied

Tags: android, textview

I want to get the number of characters which are visible in `TextView` when we have applied `android:ellipsize` in `TextView`. Suppose i have "This is dummy top stories title with multiline, This is dummy top stories title with multiline." text and i have set `"android:ellipsize="end" android:maxLines="2""` these properties in my `Textview` , so it will cut down some text and show the 3 dots. Now i want the nuumber of characters which are visible.

Comment: Please explain your problem briefly, you can post here its relevant screenshot too. So, I better understand

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15567519/8089770

Answer (score 0):

- In case of singleLine `TextView`:

  stringLength - textView.length()

would give how much text is not shown or ellipsized away in device.

- Same way in case of multiline `TextView` you can use:

  Layout textViewLayout = textview.getLayout();

  textViewLayout.getEllipsisCount(textViewLayout.getLineCount()-1)

As per Documentation at [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout.html)

```
getEllipsisCount(int line)

Returns the number of characters to be ellipsized away, or 0 if no ellipsis is to take place.
```

**Note:** `getEllipsisCount` must be used after textview is visible/drawn.

Comment: textview.getLayout(); it is returning null here.

Comment: `textViewLayout.getEllipsisCount(textViewLayout.getLineCount()-1)` is returning 0 when string value is too large like approx 8000-9000 characters.