# on which view lifecycle event can i check chip.getLayout()?

Tags: android, text, android-lifecycle, android-chips, ellipsize

I have a Chip view.

I want to check if the text is ellipsized and if so - to replace the text with a shorter text (on run time).

I have seen this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567235/check-if-textview-is-ellipsized-in-android/15567519) to check if the text in the Chip is ellipsized.

```
Layout l = textview.getLayout();
if (l != null) {
    int lines = l.getLineCount();
    if (lines > 0)
        if (l.getEllipsisCount(lines-1) > 0)
            Log.d(TAG, "Text is ellipsized");
}
```

But I don't know at what lifecycle event should i call this method, as for this line

```
Layout l = myAccountView.getLayout();
```

I get `l = null`

I have view lifecycle (frame layout that holds my Chip)

I have tried to check on `onDraw()` and in `onLayout()`

I have also tried to call from the Dialog that hold the frame

but I know inflation is top to buttom, so it returns `l= null` on `setContentView()` as well.

Comment: try in `onResume()`

Comment: but isn't inflation top to bottom? meaning the children are not ready before the parent?

Comment: all your views will be definitely ready by `onResume()`

Comment: there is no onResume for a dialog

Comment: Maybe one of the ViewTreeObserver...Listeners will do the job, see for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733813/how-can-you-tell-when-a-layout-has-been-drawn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach 1:** Do call `myAccountView.onPreDraw();` just before `myAccountView.getLayout()`

**Approach 2 :** Using ViewTreeObserver

```
ViewTreeObserver vtObserver= myAccountView.getViewTreeObserver();
vtObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
       Layout layout = myAccountView.getLayout();  
    }
});
```

Comment: You don't need to call, it's get called by the system. I have given example to solve the issue **either** by using [onPreDraw](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#onPreDraw()) request a new layout before drawing occurs **OR** `ViewTreeObserver`. I meant to just use any not both. Recommended approach is to use `ViewTreeObserver `

Comment: thanks, i understand it's one or the other. I'm just curious to understand why `myAccountView.onPreDraw()` is needed to make my layout not null. it worked. just want to understand why is this call explicitly needed.