# Is there any way to check if a word is truncated in a TextView?

Tags: android, ellipsis

I am creating a custom text resizer for my app and I really need any way to figure out whether a word has been truncated like the word example in the image [image]

I have an idea if I can ellipsize words and then use getEllipsisCount(); but I'm not sure whether it will work and being a beginner I can't even get that done. So what should I do?

Comment: possibly this way:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923345/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-textviews-text-is-truncated

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Sorry, but that is different that one deals with truncated lines while her the problem is with words.