# How to tell if TextView text has been truncated due to singleLine="true"?

Tags: android, textview, android-singleline

I have a TextView that I would like to know if it has been truncated due to singleLine="true" in the XML.

What are some ideas to achieve this without having to pass in the displayed text but to detect this with the TextView only?

Comment: This is the exact answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923345/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-textviews-text-is-truncated

Comment: It is a possible solution but could we detect if the TextView is truncated with just the TextView itself and not having to pass in the resulting text?

Comment: all you really need is to see the length of the text once it is ellipsize and compare it to the line of text. here is another link with a good method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567235/check-if-textview-is-ellipsized-in-android

Comment: Thank you Nigel, that last answer you posted was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Great, i will update the answer for this question so people know its closed with what helped you

Comment: Thank you Nigel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer the OP was looking for was found in the following link:
[Check if textview is ellipsized in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567235/check-if-textview-is-ellipsized-in-android)

The answer basically uses this method to compare the length of the text to the ellipse count to tell if has been truncated.

```
Layout layout = textview1.getLayout();
if(layout != null) {
    int lines = layout.getLineCount();
    if(lines > 0) {
        int ellipsisCount = layout.getEllipsisCount(lines-1);
        if ( ellipsisCount > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Text is ellipsized");
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: layout might be null so call this inside textview.post {}