# Measure if Label text will be cut

Tags: xamarin.forms

I know I can use native utils to measure a string's width or bounds on each platform.

Is there a way to know if the XF Label will cut the text(using ellipsis) or indicate that due to its style,

it will let lines break into multiple lines?

Is there some parameter on a Label(Let's say I'm given a specific instance) that I can compare my measurement against?

Comment: You could use [dependency service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to invoke native utils code on specific platform.

Comment: Ok, but in that native code, can I check if the native control is actively cutting my text short? or if it is actively breaking the text into separate lines?

Comment: You could search the solution on native platform ,e,g iOS :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077109/how-to-check-if-uilabel-is-truncated , Android : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923345/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-textviews-text-is-truncated