# TextView setText problem

Tags: android, textview

I have a `TextView` and my need is to add 10 characters in that TextView by code. But when characters are greater than 10, they should be display in TextView but with `8 character + ..` of that charsequence. And when I want to read text of that TextView I must get full charsequence not `8 character + ..` . For example

tv.settext("ASDFGHJKLQ") // this is 10 characters long, so no rule required

but

`tv.settext("ASDFGHJKLOP")` // this is more than 10 characters then it should be display as 
`ASDFGHJK..` in textView, but when I retrieve the value of textview, it should return  `ASDFGHJKLOP` instead of  `ASDFGHJK..` , so how can it be done.

That textView is row of a listview.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding this to your TextView (marquee or end):

```
android:ellipsize="marquee"
```

You may also need:

```
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```

Without scrollHorizontally="true" you may still get the text wrapped rather than appended with ...  I use these very 2 lines to display a list view in my app.  The 3 long lines I have get appended correctly.

Comment: You got down-voted too, even though your answer is right. weird.

Comment: Yeah.  Usually competing answers make people mad.  It's a silly game.  You can throw a check mark on that if it worked and they can't undo that ;)

Answer (score 4):

This truncating happens because it does not fit in your list item. Reduce the font ?

or [ellipsize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666736/android-textview-automatically-truncate-and-replace-last-3-char-of-string) ?

Comment: I want truncating, but when I retrieve value, I must get original value not truncated ..

Comment: You want ellipsize.  It does exactly what you're trying to do.  It will truncate the display, but maintain the value.

Comment: @Reno and @Bill Mote Thank you both. Its working and this is perfect answer for me. and I haven't option to check both answer to right, so I am giving up votes you.

Answer (score 1):

I see only one solution. But maybe there are another solutions.

To store you string.

If string's length is greater than 10 letters set text of your TextView with 12345678..

And if you want to get right text you should take the value of the string and not of the textview.

Comment: It will not work for those text view, which are used as row of list view.

Comment: use the then an ArrayAdapter with ArrayList<String> for you listview, so you can can get for every list item the right string and set the right value for every listview item