# How to end TextView with 3 dots by using maxLength

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, ellipsize

I have a `TextView` in my layout which is `wrap_content` in `layout_width`. It is limited to maximum of 15 characters so I'm using `maxLength`.

I need to end this `TextView` with 3 dots (...) and it happens only when I give the `layout_width` a fixed size in dp, something that I don't want to do.

I know it is possible programmatically by trimming the string after the 15th character and then adding the 3 dots, but I prefer to do that by XML.

Any idea how to end the text with 3 dots and leave it wrap_content?

```xml
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/inbox_contactName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:lines="1"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:maxLength="15"
    android:textColor="#0670b4"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Comment: you may end up doing it in code\

Comment: I know, but I prefer to do it by XML.

Comment: see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666736/android-textview-automatically-truncate-and-replace-last-3-char-of-string

Comment: @Yaniv : you have try `android:ellipsize="marquee"` instead of `android:ellipsize="end"` ?

Comment: @HelmiB: It is not the same problem since there is no use there with maxLength. Anyway, I tried and it didn't solve it. Thanks

Comment: how about setting the layout_width in sp? (15 x width of letter with font size 16sp)

Comment: It's the same for me as giving it a dp width, can't do that. Thanks.

Comment: @Yaniv So how did you end up solving it?

Comment: @Ravi I didn't find any good solution for that, I've cut the string by code and not by XML. It is something that I didn't want to do, but no other choice.

Comment: @Yaniv I had a similar requirement - posted my solution as an answer just incase.

Answer (score 86):

**This will solve your problem, Use `ellipsize` Property in your XML Code**

```
android:ellipsize="end" <!-- This makes the magic ... thing -->
android:maxEms="15" <!-- Limit of the Text -->
android:singleLine="true" <!-- In case if you want everything in one line -->
```

**Edit:** `singleLine` is **deprecated**. Use `maxlines="1"` instead.

Comment: I noticed today that `singleLine="true"` and `maxlines="1"` behave differently when used with `maxWidth` and `ellipsize` - for some reason it truncates more with `maxlines` - don't know why though.

Comment: @Kirk maxEms is not working for restricting the number of digits, whereas, using maxLength, doesn't show dots.

Comment: @king possibly deprecated. At the time of answering this question, It was a working solution. If anybody knows the latest patch to this, Kindly update my answer.

Comment: Ems != number of characters

Comment: @AlexAndro what's that dude?

Comment: @Kirk Just an info! It seems to me that some people think is the same thing.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, as `maxEms` limit the width to fixed value. It will work only if you are developin app for certain resolution, which is usually never.

Comment: @Firzen Answer is targetted for the OP's question, not for you. In my answer, I didn't state what EMS does or how it behaves. Also, it's called EMS, not pixel limiter. You might be expecting a different answer to your question. Hope you understand the difference as well before you downvote.

Answer (score 24):

You cannot use both `maxLength` and `Ellipsize` although you can define `Maximum EMS` see the example below

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_hist_source_lang"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxEms="8"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

[image: It looks like this]

Comment: This is working in spite that maxLines="1" is specified because maxEms is limiting the length of string put in TextView. This kind of limitation is also specified by maxLength if it goes beyond the width of the TextView if it is specified say 150dp (then it shows the ellipsis).

Answer (score 18):

I gather (from comment) that @Yaniv already solved it using code - but this is the right way to do it (with xml). May help other users who land here. Trick is to use both toleftof *and* torightof.

```
<RelativeLayout>
...
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/some_element1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/some_element2"/>
...
<RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I only had to use `toLeftOf`.

Comment: It will not work until and unless layout_width is match_parent. It will also not work if there are three or more text views in a row (for example) and layout_width is set to wrap_content. Therefore you should limit the size of the text view's width by weight, max_length, lines, or ems.

Answer (score 14):

You can use

```
android:maxWidth="100dp"
android:maxLines="1"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Only this works for me.

Answer (score 8):

One of the easiest way is to add **Right Padding + Ellipsize**

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtvw_contentcell_subhead"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Polem sampler, Lorem Ipsum golep tolem burop yemit noski"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/caption_black_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/caption_size"
            android:paddingRight="40dp"/>
```

Here is an example Subtitle Text with char limit.
[image]

Comment: When i am using android:maxLines="3" then  how it is possible in end line of text see "..." ?

Comment: @PraveenKumarVerma sorry I dont get your question, can you add more details. Thankyou

Comment: I mean, I have TextView in set 3 lines of text and last 3rd line set "..." dotted.

Comment: @PraveenKumarVerma I believe it will work, the 3 dots only appears if the text overflow otherwise it will not. In my example I have only 1 line and my text seems too long for it, so a 3 dots appears.

Comment: yes I am trying solved my problem. Thanks neferpitou.

Comment: You should probably use paddingEnd instead of paddingRight to account for right-to-left languages. But otherwise great suggestion, this is what I wanted. :)

Answer (score 7):

use this `android:ellipsize="end"`

Answer (score 3):

Tried most of the solutions above. Using maxWidth was the key for me:

```
android:maxWidth="100dp"
android:maxLines="1"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Answer (score 2):

**Very Important:** `ellipsize = "end"` only works when  `maxLength` is set to a value that is **more than** the number of characters on one line.
You can use `wrap_content` if you align the TextView's end and start to any other view(s).

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this with Radio Button and I wanted to limit the size to one line. When I used `Android:singleline="true"`, radio button's check circle disappeared. Here's the code that finally worked:

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="1"
```

There's no need to set ems. This will probably work also in TextView and other UI components. Hope this helps to someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can just modify the `String` when it's length is above 20 to add the ellipsize.

Answer (score -1):

remove the line from xml

```
android:lines="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
```