# android:ellipsize="end" and android:maxEms not working

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I added

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxEms="8"
android:singleLine="true"
```

to my `TextView` with the intention of showing three dots at the end and max text limit of 8 but it's not working. It shows neither the dots nor any text limit.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Both of your attributes for adding 'the three dots effect' are correct

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"
```

but the effect happens only when the `TextView` does not have any free space on the screen to show the text.

To set the limit of the text in `TextView` you can use

```
android:maxLength="8"
```

but it doesn't add the three dots, and as far as I am aware you would have to do it manually.

Something like this

```
String text = "A bit longer text";
if (text.length() > 8) {
    text = text.substring(0, 8) + "...";
}
```

The `android:maxEms` is something else than previous, you can read more about it

[What is meant by Ems? (Android TextView)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053738/what-is-meant-by-ems-android-textview)

Comment: i want to show three dots in the end.. read this..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686468/end-textview-with-3-dots-with-use-of-maxlength

Comment: why is android:ellipsize="end" not working?it should show three dots in case of large text length?

Comment: How do you want to limit the text? It usualy works if your width is match_parent and you have more text than it can into one line.

Comment: I want to limit text to maximum 8 characters and if more than that are there then it should show three dots..

Comment: try `android:maxLength="8"`

Comment: @Marko Reducing `android:maxEms="8"` value  to `android:maxEms="4"` also solved my issue..

Comment: @AndroidLearner this is not the right approach. `maxEms` means how many '**M**' charachters can fit in your `TextView`. You should avoid using it, since it is wrong. You can get a better explanation from the link in my answer.

Answer (score 8):

`ellipsize` will not work with width `wrap_content`

You can directly try the following example for testing.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:text="jhakjshdkajdhkjashkjdhakjsdjas"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:lines="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I hope this will help you to resolve the issue.

Comment: ellipsize **will** work with layout_width set to wrap_content aswell, but it has to take all the available space that it has assigned on the screen.

Comment: this should be best answer

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, I accidentally had put

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences"
```

on my TextView which prevented my ellipses from showing

Comment: Yes its worked for me. After 4 hours of searching..

Comment: Nice catch man! I Changed every attribute related to the line settings and none worked. As per your answer deleted the `inputType` attribute and daamn finally the ellipsize appeared!

Answer (score 1):

set `android:layout_width="0dp"` instead of  `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

**Best Wat to use**

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:minEms="1"
        android:singleLine="true" />
```