# android java - how to know how many characters left to the end of one line?

Tags: java, android

How do I know how long should be my String to not exceed one line (so I can substring it to `myString.substing(0,maxOneLineLength-3)+"...";` and it fits one line perfectly ?

Comment: That isn't how strings work.  There is no 'end of line' until you reach a line break or your string runs out of memory.  How long your string can be before the 'end of line' depends on what is containing the string.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you have a fixed width (like a rectangle) in which you want to put some text, and you want the text to wrap(or resize to fit) when it gets to the edge of rectangle?

Comment: You may be tackling this problem from the 'wrong end' -there are layout properties for views that do this for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666736/android-textview-automatically-truncate-and-replace-last-3-char-of-string/1667339#1667339

Comment: that really depends on the size of each letter in your font

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using that on a `TextView` you should use [`android:ellipsize="end"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aellipsize) instead. Also make sure `android:singleLine="true"` is set.